# How can I get an output containing only the size for a directory?

Tags: command-line, directory

How to get directory and its subdirectories size?
I tried `du -sh .` But it also prints path.
I need a command that doesn't print path. Like:

```
$command
50kB
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `awk` to refine your output:

```
du -sh . | awk '{print $1}'
```

`print $1` specifies to print only the first column of output.

---

###### You could also make this a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# script to output only the size with no path 

du -sh "$@" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Then you could run:

```
./scriptname .
```

replacing "scriptname" with the actual name of the script.

Also, don't forget to make it executable before you run the script:

```
chmod +x ./scriptname
```

again, replacing "scriptname" with the actual name of the script.

---

###### Alternatively, as pointed out by @steeldriver:

you can also use `cut -f 1` instead of `awk`

```
du -sh . | cut -f 1
```

As a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# script to output only the size with no path 

du -sh "$@" | cut -f 1
```